# サインアップ時のメールアドレス検証などで利用する返信を意図しないメールアドレスにMXレコードの設定は必要でしょうか

Tags: mail

サインアップ時のメールアドレスの検証・メルマガ配信用のメールアドレスを用意する場合、そのメールアドレスに受信用の設定（MXレコードの登録）をする必要はあるのでしょうか。

上記のメールアドレスに対しては返信がないものと思っているので、受信設定をする必要はないと思っています。ただ、そういう場合でも基本的に設定するケースのが多い、またはそもそも設定しないことに問題があるなどご教授していただければと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

確かに不要かもしれません。

ただし、それ以前の問題として、MXレコードも用意されていないドメインからメールを相手サーバーが受信してくれるか疑問です。spamとして破棄されかねないです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。受信されない可能性があることを考えると設定しておく方が良いかもしれないですね。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

個人的には指定したほうがよいと思います。
ただ、それ以前にバウンスが発生した際にエラーメールを受け取るアドレスをきちんと指定しておくことが大切だと思います。
具体的には、メールヘッダの「Return-Pass」や「Envelope-From」で確認することができます。
このエラーメールを受け取るメールアドレスにはきちんとMXレコードを設定して、ある程度定期的にバウンスが起きていないかを監視しておいたほうがよいと思います。
また、これを設定することにより、ユーザーからメールが届いていないなどの問い合わせがあった際に、調査することが可能になるかと思います。
なお、レンタルサーバーなどでメールを送信すると、エラーメールの送信先が `ユーザー名@レンタルサーバーのホスト名` のようになっているケースをよく見かけます。
きちんとレンタルサーバーのホスト名にもMXレコードが設定されているサーバーならよいのですが、レンタルサーバーによってはレンタルサーバーのホスト名にMXレコードが設定されていないサーバーもあるため、きちんと設定しておくほうがよいでしょう。

以上、何かの参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: エンベロープfromについても教えていただきありがとうございます。とても参考になりました。